# create html elements on the serverside VS get data as JSON and create tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance

I want to create a AJAX search to find and list topics in a forum (just topic link and subject).
The question is: Which one of the methods is better and faster?

1. GET threads list as a JSON string and convert it to an object, then loop over items and create a `<li/>` or `<tr>`, write data (link, subject) and append it to threads list. (jQuery Powered)
2. GET threads list which it wrapped in HTML tags and print it (or use `innerHTML` and `$(e).html()`)

Thanks...

Comment: JQuery Approach is good n its a proven framework.What else do we need.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second method.

I figure server-side you have to either convert your data to JSON or html format so why not go directly to the one the browser understands and avoid having to reprocess it client-side. Also you can easily adapt the second method to degrade gracefully for users who have disabled JavaScript (such that they still see the results via standard non-JS links.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which way is better (I assume the second method is better as it would seem to touch the data less) but a definitive way to found out is try both ways and measure which one does better.

Answer (score 0):

'Faster' is probably the second method.

'Better' is probably subjective.

For example, I've been in situations (as a front end dev) where I couldn't alter the html the server was returning and i wished they would have just delivered a json object so i could design the page how i wanted.

Also, (perhaps not specific to your use case), serving up all the html on initial page load could increase the page size and load time.

Answer (score 0):

Server generated HTML is certainly faster if the javascript takes long time to process the JSON and populate the html.

However, for maintainability, JS is better. You can change HTML generation just by changing JS, not having to update server side code, making a delta release etc etc.

Best is to measure how slow it really is. Sometimes we think it is slow, but then you try it out in real world and you don't really see a big difference. You might have the major delay in transmitting the JSON object. That delay will still be there and infact increase if you send an html representation from the server.

So, if you bottleneck really is parsing JSON and generating html, not the transmission from server, then sending html from server makes sense.

However, you can do a lot of optimization in producing the html and parsing JSON. There are so many tricks to make that faster. Best if you show me the code and I can help you make a fast JS based implementation or can tell you to do it on the server.